# Date & Time loop in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, bashrc

I am trying to download the yesterday logs through an external API, For API I need to provide a date range from & to as input parameters.

From API I can download 1 hour log max for each call.

So if I want to download yesterday complete log. I need to call the API for 24 times with yesterday date(every hour time).

Note API will support only GMT time only. So need to provide GMT time.

> Eg :- https://abcd.com/logs?start=**FROM_DATE**&end=**TO_DATE**

1. **First time loop** it should go like below,
2. https://abcd.com/logs?start=**29-04-2018T00:00:00Z**&end=**29-04-2018T00:59:59Z**
3. **Second time loop** it should go like below
4. https://abcd.com/logs?start=**29-04-2018T01:00:00Z**&end=**29-04-2018T01:59:59Z**
5. **Last time loop** like below,
6. https://abcd.com/logs?start=**29-04-2018T23:00:00Z**&end=**29-04-2018T23:59:59Z**

This script i will add in cron schedule, so everyday once it will get triggered and download yesterday 24 hour log complete.

**Key points are**

1. Yesterday date always
2. Format GMT
3. 24 times loop

The below mentioned answers are throwing error. I started with this script, it is considering the current time and doing the loop. Instead of that loop needs to start with 00:00:00 GMT time.

```
#!/bin/bash
FROM_DATE=$(date -u -d "1 day ago" +%Y-%m-%d"T"%H":00:00""Z")
for i in {0..3}
  do
    echo "FROM_DATE : $FROM_DATE"
    TO_DATE=$(date -u +%Y-%m-%d"T"%H":59:59""Z" -d "1 day ago""$date + $i hour")
    echo "TO_DATE : $TO_DATE"
    FROM_DATE=$(date -u +%Y-%m-%d"T"%H":00:00""Z" -d "1 day ago""$date + $i hour""$date + 1 hour")
  done
```

Comment: it is considering the current time and doing the loop. Instead of that loop needs to start with 00:00:00 GMT time

Comment: Hard to read a script in a comment. I added it to the question, but please verify it. Something seems to have been eaten in the comment, so edit it to correct it.

Comment: that is correct. I took hour and appended the minutes and seconds.

Comment: Problem is my loop needs to start with GMT 00:00:00 instead of considering current hour. Please help it

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
yesterday=$(date --utc --date 'yesterday' +'%Y-%m-%d')
for hour in {0..23}
do
    printf "https://abcd.com/logs?start=%sT%02d:00:00Z&end=%sT%02d:59:59Z\n" $yesterday $hour $yesterday $hour
done
```

It won't handle the occasional leap seconds. If you need that, use this more complex code where the last range of the day may need to go from `23:00:00` to `23:59:60`, but ensure that your target application can also handle this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
yesterday=$(date --utc --date 'yesterday' +'%Y-%m-%d')
leapsecond=$(date --utc --date @$(( $(date --utc --date '00:00:00' +%s) -1 )) +'%S')
lastsecond=59

for hour in {0..23}
do
    [[ hour == 23 ]] && lastsecond=$leapsecond
    printf "https://abcd.com/logs?start=%sT%02d:00:00Z&end=%sT%02d:59:%02dZ\n" $yesterday $hour $yesterday $hour $lastsecond
done
```

Comment: the out put of the first code is like below : invalid number printf: 0
: invalid number printf: 0
T00:59:59Z), TO_DATE(2018-04-26

Comment: Like what below? Please [EDIT YOUR QUESTION to show us what you actually want](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/440409/edit), rather than expecting us to read your mind or try and interpret poorly formatted comments.

Comment: i have just modified printf to echo it is coming like this 0018-04-26sT%02d:00:00Z), TO_DATE(%sT%02d:59:59Z)\n 2018-04-26

Comment: @Jhony don't use `echo` where I've used `printf`. They're different commands for a reason.

Comment: i have created script file with the above code as test.sh and running in linux environment

Comment: ok. But how to correct those errors  invalid number printf: 0 : invalid number printf: 0 T00:59:59Z), TO_DATE(2018-04-26

Comment: Yeah. Please. How to do that?

Comment: i have tried the new code. still same error

Comment: i cant chat. I am new here

Comment: Please [fix your question to show the required output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/440409/edit).

Comment: i have API link like below.
https://abcd.com/log?start=$FROM_DATE&end=$TO_DATE
I need to call this link in a loop for 24 times by providing yesterday GMT time starting from 00 to 23 hours
For each call i can provide one hour timeframe only. That is API restriction. hope it is clear

Comment: My first time call should be[link] (https://abcd.com/received? start=$2018-04-26T00:00:00Z& end=$2018-04-26T00:59:59Z)

Comment: @Jhony since you refuse to work within my repeated request for you to UPDATE YOUR QUESTION I'm not going to correspond further.

Comment: @roiama, I am not refused to modify, if you mentioned which one is not clear, Will provide additional details.

Comment: Edited Question, Hope you can understand now. Feel free if you have doubts.

Comment: @Jhony thank you. Answer updated for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting as expected output.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {00..23}
do FROM_DATE=$(date -u -d "1 day ago" +%Y-%m-%d"T"$i":00:00Z")
echo "FROM_DATE:" $FROM_DATE | tr -d '\r'
TO_DATE=$(date -u +%Y-%m-%d"T"$i":59:59Z" -d "1 day ago")
echo "TO_DATE : $TO_DATE" | tr -d '\r'
done
```

Thanks a lot for your help